# ¿Como arreglar tamaño de imágenes WowSlider?

Tags: jquery, html

¿Cómo puedo arreglar el tamaño de imágenes? estoy utilizando WowSlider de jQuery y tengo solo 2 imágenes en el carrusel pero al pasar a la segunda siempre esa imagen pierde tamaño este es mi códgo generado por WowSlider:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tiendas El Golazo USA</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">


<!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section --> <!-- add to the <head> of your     page -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine0/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section --></head>
<body style="background: url(assets/images/fondos/fondoGris.jpg);">

<div class="principal">
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section --> <!-- add to the <body> of your page -->
<div id="wowslider-container0">
<div class="ws_images"><ul>
<li><a href="http://wowslider.com"><img src="data0/images/banner3.png" alt="wowslider.com" title="banner3" id="wows0_0"/></a></li>
<li><img src="data0/images/banner1.png" alt="banner1" title="banner1" id="wows0_1"/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
<a href="#" title="banner3"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/banner3.png" alt="banner3"/>1</span></a>
<a href="#" title="banner1"><span><img src="data0/tooltips/banner1.png" alt="banner1"/>2</span></a>
</div></div><div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.net">jquery slider</a> by WOWSlider.com v8.7</div>
<div class="ws_shadow"></div>
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/wowslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/script.js"></script>
<!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->

 <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><strong>Productos en Pacas</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#about"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="logo" >

 </div>

     <div class="contenido-izquierda">

         <div class="izqCont"> 
            <h4 style="margin-top:100px;">Somos una empresa dedicada a la venta de ropa al por mayor</h4>
         </div>             

     </div>

     <div class="central" style="background:url(assets/images/fondos/cafe.jpg)">
        <div class="myDiv">
            <img src="assets/images/camisa3.png">
            <div class="text">
                <h4>Vestido!</h4>
                <p>Este vestido es color blanco</p>
                <a id="btn" href="#">Ver</a>
            </div>  
        </div>
     </div>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de por que la segunda imagen se baja un poco y pierden el tamaño original?

Comment: podrias mostrar tu css.

Comment: Lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en el Centro de Ayuda y añade uno a la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Podrías pasarnos tu código y las imagenes que contiene para verificar?

Answer (score 0):

Quizá el problema sea que el tamaño de la imagen no coincide con el tamaño asignado al slider en el programa. Prueba editando la imagen de modo que coincidan los tamaños.

Comment: Ya hice un rezise de las imágenes son del mismo tamaño y no encuentro la razón del por que solo una de las 2 pierde tamaño

Comment: @Shaz es una respuesta. Mala, pero es una respuesta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No estoy de acuerdo, pero bueno, algún día lo discutiremos, igual ya eliminé el comentario generado.